# Html text view in flutter

Tags: html, parsing, flutter

I have HTML string that I am taking from JSON. However, when I assign it to my local variable, all the HTML tags are missing, and indentation is automatically done, however I never asked this variable to render this HTML. I need this value to be saved exactly like it is in JSON (e.g without any indentation and with tags) How do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Sharing a code snippet might help experts at Stackoverflow to help you out.

Comment: I think my explanation is more than enough to understand the issue.

Comment: You are right. The issue is understood. However if you give a code snippet, it will be easier for someone at SO to reproduce the issue, find the solution and answer your question.